# Mini 8 queens puzzle

Tags: no-computers, chess

[image]

On a 5x5 chessboard, place 5 black queens and 3 whites queens so that no queens are attacking those who are of different color. Furthermore, the numbers indicate how many queens are attacking the respective square and you can’t place queens on numbers. Please don’t use computers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Due to the 6, we can place the following few pieces:

> A2, c1, d1, e3. And we also know there is at least one other black piece on the D file, and a piece on the main diagonal.

After a little bit of trial and error from here, I found the solution:

> [image: A2,A5,B5,c1,d1,d4,e1,e4]

4 is attacked by:

> A2, B5, d1, e3

6 is attacked by all but

> B5, e4

Comment: Nice, can you give more explanations please?